# turn off "-- INSERT --" color

Tags: insert-mode, colorscheme, statusline

vim 7.4 console mode.

When in insert mode, I would like to turn off the ugly yellow when I am in insert mode.

My background is set to light, so vim should not use a light yellow for anything.

Comment: The real problem was changing what displayed when Tera Term displayed when it received a BOLD command. I would never had known without tracking it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
hi clear ModeMsg
```

in your `vimrc` or color file.